# Nodejs test case for pipeData.on('finish', ()=>{res.end()}

Tags: node.js, npm, base64, mocha.js, chai

I am using below code for reading the `base64` input string:

```
//NPM package
var base64 = require('base64-stream');
var memorystreams = require('memory-streams');

function getMyData(base64DataStr, res) {

    let base64DataStr=X10;
    let pipeData;

    pipeData= new memorystreams.ReadableStream(base64DataStr);

    pipeData.on('finish', ()=>{
        res.end(); --Sending the response
      });
}
```

and code is working fine, but i need to design the unit test case using NPM chai and Mocha, so could you please give me idea how i can write the test case to test above scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a complete example, where is res defined, where are you building up the response?

Comment: provided more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get where you want to go is turn getMyData  into an async method that returns a callback

```
function getMyData(base64DataStr, cb) {

    let base64DataStr=X10;
    let pipeData;

    pipeData= new memorystreams.ReadableStream(base64DataStr);

    pipeData.on('finish', ()=>{
        cb('send back some data');
      });
}
```

Then handle the response in the calling route where you have access to the response, so (I'm not sure why you are passing in base64DataStr just to reassign it):

```
app.get('/foo', (req, res) =>{
  getMyData('fo', _out => res.end(_out))
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your response helped me.